# JSON serialization freezes the UI

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm making a Kotlin Multiplatform project for Android and iOS. My goal is to do networking and JSON serialization in the common module, and consuming that data in the target platform.

But I have a problem: it blocks the UI on the iOS app. Downloading is fine, because it is done by networking library, but when JSON is big enough and serialization takes some time, it freezes the UI untill serialization is completed.

Here are my steps:

**Common**

Request method using ktor library:

```
class NetworkProvider {
    private val client = HttpClient()
    suspend fun request(urlString: String): String {
        return client.request<String>(urlString)
    }
}
```

Request method with JSON serialization:

```
suspend fun request(): CustomObject {
    val json = networkProvider.request("API endpoint")
    val object = Json.nonstrict.parse(CustomObject().serializer(), json)
    return object
}
```

Performing request:

```
class Downloader {
    var listener: DownloadListener? = null
    fun download() {
        CustomCoroutineScope().launch {
            val object = request()
            listener?.onCompleted(object)
        }
    }
}
```

Dispatcher and coroutine scope:

```
class UIDispatcher : CoroutineDispatcher() {
    override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            block.run()
        }
    }
}

internal class CustomCoroutineScope : CoroutineScope {
    private val dispatcher = UIDispatcher()
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = dispatcher + job
}
```

**iOS**

Implement `DownloadListener` method:

```
func onCompleted(object: CustomObject) {
    // Update the UI
 }
```

and call the request

```
downloader.download()
```

I assumed that it should be asynchronously performed in the main thread without blocking the UI.

What am I doing wrong? I tried using `withContext` when calling the coroutine but it didn't help.

Is there any way of doing heavy tasks in the common module without blocking the UI in the specific platform?

Comment: Don't run this sync

Comment: If it's going to take a long time, move it off the main thread.  Making it asynchronous only means it won't block **immediately**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your network call is complete, your Json parsing will wind up on the main thread. That will block all the other things on the main thread, including the ui. You need to send the Json parsing to a background thread. Here are some examples of concurrency with kotlin multi platform

https://github.com/touchlab/DroidconKotlin/blob/master/sessionize/lib/src/commonMain/kotlin/co/touchlab/sessionize/platform/Functions.kt

Comment: Hey @KevinGalligan, I'm having a little bit of a trouble with your code. 

My app flow is pretty much the same as krlb's, and your background task solution works great for parsing. However, when I go through the call-parse cycle my HttpClient gets frozen and cannot be used anymore, I have to create another one and that's not an acceptable solution. 
After some digging I've came to a conclusion that it all happens because coroutine continuation is passed to the `backgroundTask`, and that freezes pretty much everything in the coroutine. 
Do you have any idea how to work around this issue?

Comment: @JanStoltman The coroutine and continuation should not be frozen. They are kept in the main thread. I can't see your code, but I assume you're capturing the HttpClient in the background lambda somehow.

Comment: Summary, if you have some sample code to look at, I can speak to it better.

Comment: @KevinGalligan You can find the important parts of my code here: https://gist.github.com/JanStoltman/9c802d06c469de46f2d76ad6bfbe5a28

I use the same background task as in Droidcon. From what I understand, we pass the continuation to a JobWrapper wrapped in a lambda. Wouldn't freezing this JobWrapper freeze the whole continuation?

Comment: any idea about my question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req?noredirect=1#comment101757029_57598276

Answer (score 3):

JSON parsing being a heavy task, needs to be done on a background thread. Instead of dispatching asynchronously on the main queue, dispatch it asynchronously on the global queue.